# PostgreSQL doesn't support the COUNT(<DYNAMIC_TYPE>) function. Use suitable function or create user defined function

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql, migration

While doing migration from oracle Database to postgres. one procedure is inserting the data using select statement in oracle. Below is the query

```
INSERT INTO some_table (source_name,
                                                unique_id,
                                                source_system_name,
                                                series_definition_code,
                                                obsrv_dtm,
                                                obsrv_cd,
                                                update_dtm,
                                                rnk,
                                                file_count)
             SELECT   source_name,
                      unique_id,
                      source_system_name,
                      series_definition_code,
                      obsrv_dtm,
                      obsrv_code,
                      update_dtm,
                      rnk,
                      file_count
               FROM   (SELECT   source_name,
                                unique_id,
                                source_system_name,
                                series_definition_code,
                                obsrv_dtm,
                                obsrv_code,
                                update_dtm,
                                ROW_NUMBER ()
                                   OVER (
                                      PARTITION BY series_definition_code,
                                                   obsrv_dtm,
                                                   SUBSTR (
                                                      obsrv_code,
                                                      1,
                                                      INSTR (obsrv_code, '.', 1)
                                                      - 1
                                                   )
                                                   || '.'
                                                   || SUBSTR (obsrv_code,
                                                              INSTR (obsrv_code,
                                                                     '.',
                                                                     1,
                                                                     2)
                                                              + 1)
                                      ORDER BY update_dtm DESC NULLS LAST
                                   )
                                   rnk,
                                COUNT (
                                   DISTINCT update_dtm
                                )
                                   OVER (
                                      PARTITION BY series_definition_code,
                                                   obsrv_dtm,
                                                   SUBSTR (
                                                      obsrv_code,
                                                      1,
                                                      INSTR (obsrv_code, '.', 1)
                                                      - 1
                                                   )
                                                   || '.'
                                                   || SUBSTR (obsrv_code,
                                                              INSTR (obsrv_code,
                                                                     '.',
                                                                     1,
                                                                     2)
                                                              + 1)
                                   /*MQC 1901*/
                                   )
                                   file_count
                         FROM   (SELECT                             /*+ ORDERED */
                                       'STAGE' AS source_name,
                                          b.obsrv_id AS unique_id,
                                          a.extract_src_sys_name
                                             AS source_system_name,
                                          series_def_series_cd
                                             AS series_definition_code,
                                          obsrv_dtm AS obsrv_dtm,
                                          b.obsrv_cd AS obsrv_code,
                                          update_dtm AS update_dtm
                                   FROM   table1 c,
                                          table2 a,
                                          table3 b
                                  WHERE       a.actl_id = c.actl_id
                                          AND a.partition_id = c.partition_id
                                          AND a.actl_ref_id = b.actl_ref_id
                                          AND a.partition_id = b.partition_id
                                          AND c.partition_id = 4
                                          AND c.property_value = 'refreshdata'
                                          AND a.partition_id = 4
                                          AND a.extract_src_sys_name = 'Bentek'
                                          AND b.partition_id = 4
                                          AND b.record_deleted_flag = 'N')
                                stage_suspend) all_rows
              WHERE   all_rows.rnk <> 1 AND file_count > 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISTINCT is not implemented for window functions in Postgres (at least in your version), so you need to rewrite it without count(distinct ...)over()